# Python-Tkinter, for-loop to create pictured button

Tags: python, image, for-loop, tkinter, ttk

I'm still quiet new to programming, so maybe my question in pretty easy or even stupid. As said in the title I'm trying to programm a for loop, which creates a pictured button widget for each picuture in a certain folder. This is what I have so far:

```
import tkinter  
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import os

root = tkinter.Tk()

list_files = os.listdir(".")

for file in list_files:
    if file.endswith(".gif"):
        drink = PhotoImage(file)
        print(drink)
        b1 = ttk.Button(image=drink, text="Hello", compound="right").pack()
        l1 = ttk.Label(image=drink).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Now what I get is two widgets, one label displaying nothing and a button displaying Hello. In the shell it says drink1.gif, which is correct, because that's the only gif file in my standard python folder...

what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `PhotoImage(file='path_to_file')` to create image from path.
2. When `PhotoImage` object is garbage-collected by Python, the label is cleared. You must save reference to `drink` object somewhere: `l1.image = drink`:
   http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm
3. `widget.pack()` method return nothing.

```
import tkinter  
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import os

root = tkinter.Tk()
list_files = os.listdir(".")
for path in list_files:
    if path.endswith(".gif"):
        drink = PhotoImage(file=path)
        b1 = ttk.Button(root, image=drink, text="Hello", compound="right")
        b1.pack()
        l1 = ttk.Label(root, image=drink)
        l1.image = drink
        l1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfectly working! Thank you! This panel is awesome!!

is there a way to stick text with the picture and display it? something like a description? or should I just name the file by the text I want to be displayed?

Is there a good explanation about garbage collection? I'm not sure whether I fully got it and I think it's rather important ;)

Comment: I don't know **common** way to attach text to image. You can store description in text file: `my_image.gif` and `my_image.txt`.

Comment: About garbage collection: if you load 5 images in loop (without saving references to them), only last image will be displayed.

Comment: Okay thank you I think I get it now! the idea with .txt is good aswell, thanks guys you were really helpful!!

Answer (score 2):

`PhotoImage(file)` creates an image and gives it the *name* "drink1.gif", which is returned. If you actually want to load the file into the image, you need `PhotoImage(file = file)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are supposed to run `self.pack`, according to the Zetcode tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, this tutorial was new to me